# How to get values only from a PHP array inside multiple nested Arrays without knowing value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

it's my first question here. My PHP is sort of ok and I duplicate/modify code to get what I want usually but I'm very lost here and not sure where to get the info I need

**MAIN ISSUE I don't know what to call to get things inside ARRAY**

What I need is inside that ***Array*** of Extras. I've duplicated & modified everything I can to get these values but can't seem to figure it out. Any help is really appreciated.

The **registration, milage, condition** shown is the output of **$autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_arr**

[image: results on page for user]

Things I've tried (below but commented/removed most of it after) and what it's calling what you see in image above

The **main line** here is `<?php echo balanceTags(tz_autoshowroom_get_vehicle_specs(get_the_ID(), 'all')); ?>` which is calling all values from **Registration Date** - **100 HP** and has the inner Array I need

```
<div class="vehicle-box">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><span><?php esc_html_e('Specifications', 'autoshowroom'); ?></span>
                    </h3>
                    <?php if ($autoshowroom_detail_model || $autoshowroom_detail_make == 'yes') : ?>
                        <div class="pcd-specs">
                            <?php if ($autoshowroom_detail_make == 'yes') { ?>
                                <div>
                                    <label><?php esc_html_e('Make', 'autoshowroom'); ?></label>
                                    <span>
                                        <?php $autoshowroom_vehicle_make = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'make');
                                        foreach ($autoshowroom_vehicle_make as $make) {
                                            $ve_make = $make->slug;
                                            echo esc_attr($make->name);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if ($autoshowroom_detail_model == 'yes') { ?>
                                <div>
                                    <label><?php esc_html_e('Model', 'autoshowroom'); ?></label>
                                    <span>
                                        <?php $autoshowroom_vehicle_make = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'model');
                                        foreach ($autoshowroom_vehicle_make as $make) {
                                            echo esc_attr($make->name);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <div class="clr"></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
                    <?php 

                    echo implode( ", ", balanceTags(tz_autoshowroom_get_vehicle_specs(get_the_ID(), 'all')));

                    echo '<br /><br />';
                    echo $color_choices['inactiveTags'];
                    echo $autoshowroom_detail_model; // yes
                    
                    print_r($car_extras); 
                    echo '<br /><h1>neww</h1>';
                    echo $autoshowroom_detail_extras;

                    echo balanceTags(tz_autoshowroom_get_vehicle_specs(get_the_ID(), $autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_arr));

                    echo '<br /><h1>===</h1>';
                    echo $autoshowroom_detail_extras;
                    echo '<br /><h1>=5==</h1>';
                    echo implode(",",$autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_values);

                    echo implode( ", ", $autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_arr ); 
                    echo '<br /><p>===</p>';

                    // actual data
                    echo implode( ", ", $car_extras ); 
                    print_r($car_extras);
                    

                    echo $autoshowroom_detail_extras;
                    echo implode( ", ", balanceTags(tz_autoshowroom_get_vehicle_specs(get_the_ID(), 'autoshowroom_detail_extras')));
                    echo implode( ", ", $autoshowroom_TZVehicle_specs );  
                    echo implode( ", ", $autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_arr );  

                    echo $autoshowroom_detail_model;
                    echo $autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_arr;

                    echo tz_autoshowroom_get_vehicle_specs(get_the_ID(),$autoshowroom_specifications_arr);

                    // show extras after make model
                                    
                    echo balanceTags(tz_autoshowroom_filter_vehicle_price(get_the_ID(),$showmsrp));
                    echo balanceTags($autoshowroom_text_title);
                    echo balanceTags( $name ); 
                    

                    
                    ?>

                    <?php echo balanceTags(tz_autoshowroom_get_vehicle_specs(get_the_ID(), 'all')); ?>


                    <?php
                    if (class_exists('Comment_Rating_Output')):
                        $average_rating = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz-average-rating', true);
                        if (empty($average_rating)) {
                            $average_rating = 0;
                        }
                        echo '<div class="tz-average-rating"><div class="tz-rating tz-rating-' . esc_attr($average_rating) . '"></div></div>';
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Using this `echo implode( ", ", $autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_arr );` I'm able to get the actual STRING values from wordpress db which shows the *registration, milage, condition*

So here's what I have for some of the code to give an idea from **single-vehicle.php** which is what I use to show front end user results *(not sure if it's better to just add all three files needed for this here)*  `$autoshowroom_portfolio_specifications_arr = ot_get_option('autoshowroom_TZVehicle_specs');` and below in **theme-options.php** (*notice the **choices***)

```
        array(
            'id' => 'autoshowroom_TZVehicle_specs',
            'label' => esc_html__('Choose Specifications to display', 'autoshowroom'),
            'desc' => esc_html__('Specifications has checked will display on inventory page(You should choose max is 3 item to nice view)', 'autoshowroom'),
            'std' => '',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'section' => 'TZVehicle',
            'rows' => '',
            'post_type' => '',
            'taxonomy' => '',
            'min_max_step' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'condition' => '',
            'operator' => 'and',
            'choices' =>
                tz_autoshowroom_get_fields()
        ),
```

and the function is

```
function tz_autoshowroom_get_fields() {
global $car_dealer;

if (is_plugin_active('progression-car-dealer-master/progression-car-dealer.php')) {
    $fields = $car_dealer->fields->get_registered_fields('specs');
    $auto_fields = array();

    if ($fields != null) {
        foreach ($fields as $i => $field) {
            $auto_fields[$i]['value'] = $field['name'];
            $auto_fields[$i]['label'] = $field['label'];
            $auto_fields[$i]['src'] = '';
        }
    } else {
        $auto_fields[0]['value'] = 'none';
        $auto_fields[0]['label'] = 'no Specifications ';
        $auto_fields[0]['src'] = '';
    }

    return $auto_fields;
}
```

}

which uses the following to show vehicle options in multiple arrays from theme options file

My duplicate/modified codes below in **theme-options.php**  (*again notice the **choices***)

```
        array(
            'id' => 'autoshowroom_Detail_show_extras',
            'label' => esc_html__('Show Extras', 'autoshowroom'),
            'desc' => '',
            'sdt' => 'yes',
            'type' => 'select',
            'section' => 'TZVehicleDetail',
            // 'section' => 'TZVehicle',
            'choices' => array(
                array(
                    'value' => 'yes',
                    'label' => esc_html__('Show', 'autoshowroom'),
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => 'no',
                    'label' => esc_html__('Hide', 'autoshowroom'),
                )
            )
        ),
```

in **class-car-dealer-fields.php** is where I have the actual values of these options/extras set and I've duplicated **color_choices** as the example to get the following inside `public function __construct()`

```
    $car_extras = array_unique( array_merge( array (
        __( 'Auxiliary heating', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'ABS', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Central locking', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Power Assisted Steering', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Cruise control', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Immobilizer', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Warranty', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Electric windows', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Financing', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Another', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
        __( 'Last', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
    ), $this->get_meta_values( 'extras', 'vehicle' ) ));
    $car_extras = array_combine( $car_extras, $car_extras);
```

and here are some other settings also inside the `public function __construct() {` but inside this array  `$this->built_in = array(`

```
        'milage' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Mileage', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'name' => 'milage',
            'type' => 'number',
            'instructions' => __( 'The number of miles travelled or covered', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => __( 'e.g. 70000', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => get_option( 'options_pcd_milage_unit', 'mi' ),
            'sort' => 20
        ),
        'condition' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Condition', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'name' => 'condition',
            'instructions' => '',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'choices' => array(
                'new' => __( 'New', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
                'used' => __( 'Used', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
                'preowned' => __( 'Certified Pre-Owned', 'progression-car-dealer' )
            ),
            'default_value' => 'new',
            'other_choice' => 0,
            'sort' => 30
        ),
        'color' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Exterior Color', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'name' => 'color',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'choices' => $color_choices,
            'other_choice' => 1,
            'save_other_choice' => 1,
            'default_value' => 'silver',
            'layout' => 'horizontal',
            'sort' => 40,
        ),
        'interior' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Interior Color', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'name' => 'interior',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'choices' => $int_color_choices,
            'other_choice' => 1,
            'save_other_choice' => 1,
            'default_value' => 'black',
            'layout' => 'vertical',
            'sort' => 50,
        ),
        'transmission' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Transmission', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'name' => 'transmission',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'choices' => array (
                'auto' => __( 'Automatic', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
                'manual' => __( 'Manual', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'layout' => 'horizontal',
            'sort' => 60,
        ),
        'engine' => array (
            'label' => __( 'Engine', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'name' => 'engine',
            'instructions' => __( 'The displacement the engine gives in Litres', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'append' => 'L',
            'placeholder' => '4,1',
            'sort' => 70,

            'min' => 0,
            'max' => 10
        ),
        // eddie
        // show in car editor specifications tab
        'extras' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Extras', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
            'name' => 'extras',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'choices' => $car_extras,
            'other_choice' => 55,
            'save_other_choice' => 55,
            'default_value' => '',
            'layout' => 'horizontal',
            'sort' => 95,
        ),
```

I also duplicated one of these arrays to get the checkbox typeextras

```
public function register_field( $args ) {

    // ACF requires a unique key per field so lets generate one
    $key = md5( serialize( $args ));

    if ( empty( $args['type'] )) {
        $args['type'] = 'number';
    }
    $type = $args['type'];

    if ( 'taxonomy' == $type ) {
        $field = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'key' => $key,
            'label' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'type' => 'taxonomy',
            'instructions' => '',
            'taxonomy' => '',
            'field_type' => 'select',
            'allow_null' => 1,
            'load_save_terms' => 1,
            'return_format' => 'id',
            'multiple' => 0,
            'sort' => 0,
            'group' => 'overview'
        ) );
    } else if ( 'radio' == $type ) {
        $field = wp_parse_args( $args, array (
            'key' => $key,
            'label' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'instructions' => '',
            'choices' => array(),
            'other_choice' => 1,
            'save_other_choice' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
            'layout' => 'horizontal',
            'sort' => 0,
            'group' => 'specs'
        ) );
    } else if ( 'checkbox' == $type ) {
        $field = wp_parse_args( $args, array (
            'key' => $key,
            'label' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'instructions' => '',
            'choices' => array(),
            'layout' => 'vertical',
            'sort' => 0,
            'multiple' => 1,
            'group' => 'specs'
        ) );
    } else {
        $field = wp_parse_args( $args, array (
            'key' => $key,
            'label' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'type' => 'number',
            'instructions' => '',
            'default_value' => '',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'min' => 0,
            'max' => '',
            'step' => '',
            'sort' => 0,
            'group' => 'specs'
        ) );
    }
    $field = apply_filters( 'pcd/register_field', $field );
    $this->fields[$field['name']] = $field;
```

Finally also in **class-car-dealer-fields.php** file inside `register_field_group(array` there are many arrays of settings for the admin (is where the client would select what extras to show in the front end but **this part actually works** except for some extra weirdness *highlighted in red below* at the end which seems to be a string in the db (I removed it from db and it came back after selecting some options and saving.

```
array (
                            'label' => __( 'Checkboxes field', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
                            'name' => 'pcd_checkboxes',
                            'display' => 'table',
                            'min' => '',
                            'max' => '',
                            'sub_fields' => array (
                                array (
                                    'key' => 'field_52816dc9ffee11',
                                    'label' => __( 'Checkboxes to Customize', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
                                    'name' => 'pcd_checkboxes',
                                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                                    'instructions' => __( 'Selected fields will be used', 'progression-car-dealer' ),
                                    'choices' => $choices,
                                    'default_value' => '',
                                    'layout' => 'horizontal',
                                )
                            ),
                        ),
```

[image]

Settings below in WP but this was to mainly get what I need into the WP post page so I don't need to create more

[image]

Comment: Anyone on this please??